# Use Turpentine in a mutliple Magento sites

Tags: cache, varnish, turpentine

I have a server with two Magento websites and a Varnish instance.
They are using different domain names.

I setup the first website and the cache works well.
In the second website, instead, cache not works.

I read that Turpentine didn't support multiple backend.
In the release 0.6.7. Turpentine supports them?

Thanks

Comment: are they two separate installations or the same core?

Comment: no they are two separate installations with different url

Answer (score 0):

Varnish/Turpentine does support multiple back-ends - of the *same* install of Magento, for load-balancing.

It is *not* likely to work well if you try to have two separate installations of Magento (with Turpentine) trying to use the same Varnish instance. It's better to have one instance of Varnish for each site, running on different IP addresses.